# To which extent are gases subject to granular convection?

Tags: gas

It is well known that light gases tend to diffuse upward (see [this PSE question and answer)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348700/why-do-lighter-atoms-and-molecules-diffuse-upwards). Helium is even slowly escaping the Earth, because many molecules have velocities higher than the escape one, near the space boundary.

On the other hand, it is also well known that bigger cereals tend to be on the top of a (shaken) cereal bag. This effect is called [granular convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granular_convection), but seems to go in counter with the lighter object moving higher.

Thus, I guess that gas molecules (or atoms) are subject to several forces and effects, even granular convection. My question is, to which extent is granular convection acting on gas molecules composing the atmosphere?

Comment: In the atmosphere, this effect is called turbulent diffusion. The dust particles are a thousand times denser than the surrounding air rise to a height of several kilometers.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks for the information! However I am more interested in the molecules themselves than dust particles. I suspect the effect becomes less relevant the smaller the particle, or the bigger it is, compared to a regime where it is dominant.